# How is writing a C interface easier in Ruby than Perl?

Tags: ruby, perl, cextension

According to the [official ruby About page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/) it's easier to extend Ruby with C than Perl. I'm not a (perl) XS guy, but I find it dirt simple to write something quick and simple with [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline%3a%3aC), so why is it easier in Ruby?

> Writing C extensions in Ruby is easier than in Perl or Python, with a very elegant API for calling Ruby from C. This includes calls for embedding Ruby in software, for use as a scripting language. A SWIG interface is also available.

Any further explanation from those that do more C extensions would be useful.

Comment: I think this has a lot of potential to degenerate into a geek fight, And there's nothing so petty and pointless as a geek fight. And, BTW, [ed](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed.msg.html) >> vi > emacs, Linux > FreeBSD, etc.

Comment: There isn't a single answer yet -- no need for your distractive negative speculation.

Comment: If you want this to be anything but totally subjective, you're going to have to provide more structure than a statement on a marketing page. Perhaps rephrase the question? "Provide examples of C extensions that are easy to write with Ruby"? Or perhaps even simpler... "what is a good tutorial for extending Ruby with C?"

Comment: Why? I don't want to stifle the question.. Certainly it has some value on it's face.. What's the value? Why is Ruby better than Python and Perl when it comes to writing C extensions?

Comment: Preemptive vote to reopen. I want to see someone compare writing extensions in Ruby and Perl.

Comment: "And there's nothing so petty and pointless as a geek fight". Or funny.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Full disclosure, I am a Perl programmer)

The [Ruby C API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/doxygen/current/modules.html) certainly looks much nicer than [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html)'s.  It looks like a regular C library with functions that correspond to Ruby code.  Perl's API is a mess of macros within macros within macros and magic threading flags.  Using the Perl API outside of the Perl core is certainly a secondary concern.  Ruby definitely wins on not being bowel clenchingly terrifying.

While Ruby has a better C API, Perl has the better tutorials on how to do anything with it.  The generated Ruby documentation lacks any sort of cohesive tutorial or often any descriptive text at all.  It's possible I'm looking in the wrong place [but that's all that was offered](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/).  In contrast, the Perl API documentation is hand written prose with useful information about what each function does.  In addition, [there's over a dozen documents in the core docs about using Perl and C](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-internals.html).  I'd say Perl wins on docs.

FFI looks quite impressive.  The closest thing Perl has to FFI is [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C) which is a wrapper around the mess of XS.  It's primary use is to [inline C code into your Perl program](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C-Cookbook#Hello,_world), but you can also use it to [access C library functions](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C-Cookbook.pod#Automatic_Function_Wrappers).

Here's a trivial example similar to nash's getpid example.

```
use Inline
  C             => Config       =>
  ENABLE        => "AUTOWRAP";

use Inline C => q{ int getpid(); };

print getpid();
```

Now, I am cheating because technically getpid returns pid_t on my system, but that's just an integer.  FFI seems to have an awful lot of special cased code for getpid, so I suspect it's ease of use will correspond directly to whether FFI has already taken care of it.  Trivial examples are trivial.  It would be interesting to see what happens when typical complications arise, such as functions that return pre-allocated memory and have odd types and throw around structs.

While FFI and Inline::C can be used to do the same thing, how they do it looks very, very different.  Inline::C is actually compiling and caching C code.  FFI is somehow not doing any compiling.  I'm not sure if that's really for real, or if the compilation is done for you at install time for common libraries.

In addition, FFI smooths the portability problems across the various Ruby implementations and their different ways of calling native APIs.  This is something Inline::C doesn't have to do, and quite frankly it's amazing if it really works.  One benefit is the FFI interface is much smoother than Inline::C.  With Inline::C, it's very clear that you're writing a wrapper around a C compiler.

Comment: Boy, for someone who was hesitant to accept the question as worded this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks! I'll accept it in a few days if not more tremendously awesome has been given.

Comment: @nash's answer provided the missing structure.  Also FFI caught my curiosity.

Comment: There are some FFI projects for Perl now

Comment: @JoelBerger Know their names off the top of your head?

Comment: @Schwern, [David Mertens](https://github.com/run4flat) has been working on this, especially for integration with PDL. I'm actually holding him up a bit since he wants to distribute some libraries with my [Alien::Base](http://p3rl.org/Alien::Base) project, which is still slogging. Note that I said _projects_ since I don't know if they are complete (and hence released) but I know he is having some success.

Comment: I found this link informative: http://www.rottenrei.be/posts/2009-10-18-ruby-c-extension/

Answer (score 6):

With FFI it's very easy to extend Ruby with C. This is an example from [github](https://github.com/ffi/ffi)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ffi'
module Foo
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib FFI::Library::LIBC
  attach_function :getpid, [ ], :int
end
puts "My pid=#{Foo.getpid}"
```

> You don’t need a compiler installed on
>   your system to be able to run FFI
>   extensions. On linux, you also do not
>   need to install the development
>   versions of libraries, just the
>   runtime versions. Of course, the
>   libraries you link against will need
>   to have been compiled at some point,
>   but odds are you won’t have had to do
>   it.

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/why-use-ffi

Comment: AFAIK, similar modules are available for Perl.

Comment: I keep seeing people who say FFIs are SOOO useful, but how do they fare with real-world complex data types? Wrapping functions of integers and floating point values is only of limited use.

Comment: what complex types? [https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Structs](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Structs), [https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Enums](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Enums), [https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Types](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Types)